# new window title in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter in python and am not able to figure out what the syntax below does exactly.

```
oldtitle=window.newtitle()
```

Removing this line from the code doesn't makes any difference to the output.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
root.title('to')
main=Toplevel(root)
tk=main.title()#<---this line
main.title('hello world')
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the line `tk=main.title()` does is to get the title of `main`.
Here is a demo using your own code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
root.title('to')
main=Toplevel(root)
main.title('hello world')
tk=main.title() # Note I moved this line to here
print(tk)       # This will print 'hello world'
mainloop()
```

The line `print(tk)` will print the title of `main` which is *hello world*.

If you want to set a different title then use this synatax instead: `tk = main.title('Some new title')` (or simply `main.title('Some new title')` if you do not need to save the title string into an other variable):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
root.title('to')
main=Toplevel(root)
main.title('hello world')
tk=main.title('Some new title') # or simply: main.title('Some new title') 
mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Note: avoid using `tk` as your personal variable name because the recommended way to import `tkinter` is: `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: Thanks , I couldn't have figured it out on my own.